# Progress Bar over getOpenFileName

Tags: python, qt, pyside

In my application I have the following line which opens a file dialog window. Once I get the file name, I do a bunch of processing which takes quite some time, and once this is done the workspace is ready for the user.

```
filename, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', os.curdir, "*.cws")
```

The file dialog is a modal window (by default), which is great, because it's preventing the user from doing stupid stuff while the workspace is not ready for use yet. I want to put a progress bar somewhere to give a sense of how much has be processed. I made another dialog window which displays a progress bar and some other information.

Now, since the file dialog window is modal, it just sits there frozen while my workspace is processing, and the progress dialog only pops up after everything is done.

I've looked into setting the file dialog window to not modal, but I don't think that is possible. I was thinking to maybe force it to close, and immediately have my progress dialog window pop up and take over the modality. How can I close the file dialog window programmatically? I don't know how to get a reference for the form.

Or perhaps you have a better suggestion on how to address this?

Comment: The problem is that you do some heavy processing after closing the file dialog, which blocks the events from being processed. You should think about doing this heavy processing in another thread. The modality of your file dialog isn't causing the problem.

Comment: The processing starts as soon as I receive the file name from the file dialog window. The window itself is still open. So do you mean that the *close event* cannot be executed because of my own heavy processing? I'm going to give it a try in another thread as you suggested. So then I should have this other thread pop up the modal progress window, to prevent the user from doing anything else? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the close event won't be processed until after your heavy processing is complete. This `other thread` should do the heavy processing, it should not do any GUI work. Keep GUI related stuff in your main thread, and move the heavy work to a new worker thread. The modal progress window should be created and shown in your main thread.

Comment: I just did this, and yep, works great! I was actually wondering what causes the file dialog to close since it didn't close as soon as it returned the file name. Cool. Now, if my progress bar is in the main thread, how will I pass information to it from the new thread, regarding the progress status? Is it bad style to have the new thread show the progress bar?

Comment: Yes, you should really keep your GUI stuff in the main thread. To pass information from your worker thread to your main thread regarding the progress status, you can use signals and slots.

Comment: If there is no need for progress bar, is it considered bad style to purposely prevent the open file window from closing by starting the heavy processing right away? For example in another section of my application, I have my application open a tiff stack, where you don't know before hand how many pages there are in the tiff. The only way to do it is to iterate through the tiff stack once until it finishes. So I can't exactly have a progress bar because I dont know the total. I just let my open file window hang (on purpose) until it's done traversing everything. What's a good way to do this?

Comment: You can show a busy indicator by setting the progress bar's min and max value to 0. From the docs: `If minimum and maximum both are set to 0, the bar shows a busy indicator instead of a percentage of steps. This is useful, for example, when using QNetworkAccessManager to download items when they are unable to determine the size of the item being downloaded.` It is pretty much always bad for the user if the application hangs.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to prevent the user from closing that progress dialog? Everything works fine now, except that if the user does close the window, they can mess with the UI before the workspace is ready. I tried to join the two threads, but then I'm back to the same problem with the open file dialog not being able to close.

Comment: You can of course [set the cancel button to 0](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qprogressdialog.html#setCancelButton). They can still use the close button on the title bar, but you can hide that by setting the window flags and removing the `Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint`. The user will still be able to close the dialog by pressing the `Esc`-key. To disable this you can install an event filter on your progress dialog and filter out the key event for `Esc`-key.

Answer (score 1):

As thuga mentioned, your application event loop is stuck by your heavy processing.
So events (and especialy paint events) are not processed while your processing is running causing the GUI to freeze.

In my opinion, you have 2 options:

**Force events to be processesed (not very classy but may work):**

It depends on how your "heavy processing" is done.
Assuming the code hanging the loop is "under your hands" (not in a third party lib).
You can add as much call to [QApplication.processEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qcoreapplication.html#id-b3f951cb-47f2-4a61-8225-c26973d37318) as you can in it.

If the processing is loop based, it can look like:

```
for item in itemList:
    ...processitem...
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
```

This as the main drawback of adding dependencies to GUI in parts of code that should not be aware of.
If your code is not loop based then you'll have to add several calls to processEvents that will pollute the processing code.

**Stop hanging the event loop (more complicated but more maintainable)**

That means you will have to deal with Threads and/or subprocesses as thuga suggested.
This solution assumes that GUI code and business code are separated well enough.

You can have a look at [this article from Qt Quarterly](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html) that gives some highlights on this issue.
Because of python Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) you may not see better results with threads.
Consider using the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing) library.

Comment: On the first option: a callback mechanism can be used to keep the GUI separate from the backend. The backend just registers a handler which it calls with a frequency that can be set by the caller. An example of this technique is [sqlite3.set_progress_handler](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.set_progress_handler).